# Unity Camera Target Texture Render Texture How To Get Masks To Work?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, shader

I'm looking at using Camera TartetTexture RenderTexture functionality for less processing intensive menu transitions but I'm having some trouble. Every texture I render out from the camera doesn't have masks working. I can see the whole version of every graphic on the screen. How can I get it rendering keeping the masks in tact? It is also failing to render any of my spawned prefabs. Either that or they could be hidden behind the unmasked graphics.

Also, I was told to render to a material. None of the shaders I've tried have supported the masks (don't know if that's really the problem) or have looked like the original image. They all look dark and moody, with the occasional weird alpha channel in the upper left corner. How can I get the image looking just like my screen?

My menus are all on a Screen Space - Overlay canvas, so they shouldn't need to be lit.